# Method with Objective-C selector conflicts - 'with' at the end

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

After upgrading to Xcode 6.3.2.

I have two functions with (so I thought) different calls:

```
func someFunction(#str: String)
{

}

func someFunctionWith(#str: String)
{

}
```

The word 'With' seems to be added (?) to `someFunction(#` after the `#` sign.

The error I get is:

> *"Method 'someFunctionWith(str:)' with Objective-C selector 'someFunctionWithStr:' conflicts with method 'someFunction(str:)' with the same Objective-C selector"*

The compiler is flagging this as selector conflicts, however, **`someFunctionWithStr:`** is not **`someFunction(str:)`**, or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#str` will be translated to `withStr` in objc. You can use the `@objc(someOtherSelectorName:)` annotation to specify a different selector name for objc and avoid the conflict.